# Extend existing Hibernate object with new object in new table

Tags: hibernate

I have existing table Attribute containing string attributes and link to AttributeType table, all implemented throughout the application.

```
public class AttributeDTO {

    private Long id;
    private AttributeTypeDTO attributeType;
    private String value;

...
}
```

I would like to add new Attribute type with a complex value (a Contact with name, forename, address, ...) which would be contained in it's own table. The new class ContactAttribute would extend the old one and based on the AttributeDTO#attributeType would either the Attribute or ContactAttribute be returned. The link (kind of foreign key) would be stored in the string value of the original Attribute table.

The question is, whether this is somehow possible to do automatically with Hibernate? I am of course expecting some alteration to the design - probably a discriminator column added to the Attribute table? And/Or making the Attribute abstract and split it into StringAttribute and ContactAttribute?

Thanks for ideas

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to model this on the database as a table? Do you plan to search for values through queries? If not, just continue to use a string on the database side and do some kind of JSON encoding here. You can model the values in whatever way you want with the JSON encoding, but avoiding the use of a separate table will usually help with performance. Using a separate table for value is a common pitfall of the EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) model which you can read a lot about on the internet. Ideally, you should just have a single JSON column on the entity table that contains all the attribute values encoded as JSON. Most databases nowadays support creating indexes on values within the JSON column, so performance even for querying purposes should not be a problem

Comment: Thanks for the analysis - I am mostly worried about existing code "compatibility", because it is quite rooted into the app and we are (unfortunatelly) accessing directly the value of the DB object. If I were to change the value to JSON I would not be able to return specific class from Hibernate (now with discriminator i can distinguish and return either this or that class) and would have to always check if that is the contact or value. For future framework I would probably go the way you suggested

Comment: You can encode this in JSON e.g. `{ "str": "myString" }` vs. `{ "contact": 123 }` and read that with Jackson into a DTO `class MyJson { String str; Integer contact; }`. The presence of a value can be used to determine the attribute type.